# Question about explain Analyze for MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
-- Explain
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT A.ActivityName
FROM Activity A
WHERE A.ActivityName NOT IN (
  SELECT SP.ActivityName
  FROM SummerPlan SP
  WHERE SP.ParkName IN ('Bear Brook', 'Pawtuckaway', 'Bradley Palmer')
);

-- Explain Analyze
EXPLAIN ANALYZE A.ActivityName
FROM Activity A
WHERE A.ActivityName NOT IN (
    SELECT SP.ActivityName
    FROM SummerPlan SP
    WHERE SP.ParkName IN ('Bear Brook', 'Pawtuckaway', 'Bradley Palmer')
);
```

My code above gives me error

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT DISTINCT A.ActivityName
> FROM Activity A WHERE A.Activity' at line 1

My professor requires we use EXPLAIN ANALYZE. I am confused why it won't work. I am using the latest version of MySQL workbench.

I would like the code to run and show the results of Explain Analyze.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running? `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` wasn't introduced until MySQL 8.0

Comment: You can check the version of MySQL Server with this query: `SELECT VERSION();`. The version of the server might be different from the version of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Thank you for modifying my code so its easier to read. I am currently using 8,.2.0 when I run SELECT VERSION();

Comment: The syntax to use Explain Analyze is explained in the docs at: [EXPLAIN Analyze](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/explain.html#explain-analyze). Also, verify that your version of MySQL Workbench supports MySQL Server 8.2.

Comment: Hey so I ran the code again with zero changes on a ubuntu machine and it worked fine. Same version of server and workbench. Seems like something on my windows PC doesn't play nice with Explain Analyze.  To anyone else having the same issue, please try on mac or linux.